# How do I format elements in the new Resource Chart

Tags: anychart

Based on [this AnyChart example](http://playground.anychart.com/gallery/7.12.0/Resource_Chart/Development_Team_Plan_(Time_Tracking_On)), I would like to update the chart so that

1. Percentage is included on the bar representing an activity. For example, the text in the first blue bar would be "Gantt timeline 2h (25%)".
2. The height of the activity bars set to a smaller value, to reduce the amount of vertical scrolling that the user would be required to use.
3. Configure tooltips
4. Control which activities are included/excluded from the over-allocation calculation

I realize this new chart type is in beta, so any helpful hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is impossible with AnyChart API directly, but you can easily calculate the percentage value. if I got you right it is the percentage of time spent on this task in a day from the total amount of working hours a day.
2. You can achieve the desired result with this code:

   ```
   chart.pixPerHour(30);
   chart.minRowHeight(80);
   ```
3. This feature will be available in our upcoming version (7.13.0 ETA: Feb 2017)
4. At the moment it is impossible, but we'll take this feature request into the consideration, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: 1. This works for me. I append the percentage calculation to the activity.name.
2. This works as well.
3. I'm looking forward to the next release.
4. Thanks for considering this.